# Update a column separated by comma for multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table Userinfo_attarea:

```
id  employee_id area_id
182521  4391    2
182522  4391    3
```

Personnel_area:

```
id  areaid
1   Area Name
2   PROJECT80
3   PROJECT69
```

When i update it works fine foe single value but i need a column with multiple values separeted by comma as mentioned below

Expected Output:

```
areaname
PROJECT80,PROJECT69
```

i am using following query for update

```
UPDATE  employee 
SET    employee.areaname = p.areaname 
FROM    employee join userinfo u
 on u.badgenumber=employee.emp_reader_id join userinfo_attarea ua on ua.employee_id=u.userid join personnel_area  p on ua.area_id=p.id
JOIN inserted I ON u.userid= I.employee_id
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
Update E set areaname = T.areaname from @Employee E
Inner Join
(
    Select employee_id,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(areaid AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
        FROM (
        Select U.employee_id,P.areaid from @Userinfo_attarea U 
        Inner Join @Personnel_area P on U.area_id = P.id
    ) B
        WHERE employee_id = A.employee_id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
    .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') areaname from
    (
    Select U.employee_id,P.areaid from @Userinfo_attarea U 
    Inner Join @Personnel_area P on U.area_id = P.id
    ) A
    GROUP BY employee_id
) T on T.employee_id = E.id
```

Working [demo](http://rextester.com/WCEXM43979)